# Do we need to add services and Repositories beans in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am working on a spring mvc project where I have `controller`,`repository` and `services`.I have created one controller which I added to the bean but after accessing the url I get a error stating:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/<courseapp/v2/api/courses] in 
DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'.
```

My bean config:

```
<bean id="courseController" class="com.courses.api.CourseController">
</bean>
```

Do I need to add beans for `Service` and `Repository` classes too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. `DispatcherServlet` failed to map the URL entered to  any of the routes registered in the controllers `CourseController` in your case.
Check for any misspelling of the routes, also verify that `url-pattern` tag is well configured in `web.xml`.
[Click here for info](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-404-error)

Comment: I have tried them,its not wokring. Do I need to add service and repository to the beans.xml too?